# android implement "READ MORE" button like play store

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I wanna implement "read more" functionality in my app like google play store in android.Please help me what kind aproaches they had used?

[image]

Comment: This is a simple UI, perhaps a LinearLayout, with some other embedded ones.  This is too generic a question (what have you tried already?)

Comment: When you click Read More button this UI is displayed with animation and action baris changed.